# R: repeat linear regression for all variables and save results in a new data frame

Tags: r, loops, regression

I have a data frame named “dat” with 10 numeric variables (var1, var2,var3,var4 , var5,…var 10),  each with several observations…

```
dat

   var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 var6 var7 var8 var9 var10 
1    12    5   18   19   12 17   11   16   18   10
2     3    2   10    6   13 17   11   16   18   10
3    13   15   14   13    1 17   11   16   18   10
4    17   11   16   18   10 17   11   16   18   10
5     9   13    8    8    7 17   11   16   18   10
6    15    6   20   17    3 17   11   16   18   10
7    12    5   18   19   12 17   11   16   18   10
8     3    2   10    6   13 17   11   16   18   10
9    13   15   14   13    1 17   11   16   18   10
```

...

I would like to write a code to repeat the same function for all the variables (except the first) in a data frame. 
The function should analyse the linear regression between var 1 and all the other variables (var2, var3, var4, var5) each at time, using the lm() function

e.g. 
cycle 1: linear regression between var 1 and var 2

```
lm(var1~var2, data=dat)
```

cycle 2: linear regression between var 1 and var 3,

```
lm(var1~var3, data=dat)
```

cycle 3: linear regression between var 1 and var 4

```
lm(var1~var4, data=dat)
```

and so on…

I would also like that the results from each cycle will be saved in a new data frame named “results”, having the following structure

```
Var_tested  Correlation_coefficient         P_value_correlation     R_squared
Var2        corr_coeff_var2                 p_value_var2            R_sq_var2
Var3        corr_coeff_var3                 p_value_var3            R_sq_var3
Var4        corr_coeff_var4                 p_value_var4            R_sq_var4
```

With each rows reporting data the results of each correlation.
Is it possible?

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Why do you want this? Why not analyze the effect of all variables together? Are you trying to p-hack your way out of this?

Comment: each variables (var2, var3,var4) represent the result of a different test which tries to estimate var1. I want to see which one has the best correlation. Having the results in that data.frame would be the best way to do further analysis...

Comment: dear @user2974951, it's really not nice to suggest the OP is doing p-hack without clarifying. MarianoCGiglio, I think you can consider fitting predictor (i.e var1..var10) under a model, lm(var ~.). You will see that if some predictors are correlated or have interactions, gives u a different result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following code to have the desired output

```r
data <- structure(list(var1 = c(12L, 3L, 13L, 17L, 9L, 15L, 12L, 3L, 
13L), var2 = c(5L, 2L, 15L, 11L, 13L, 6L, 5L, 2L, 15L), var3 = c(18L, 
10L, 14L, 16L, 8L, 20L, 18L, 10L, 14L), var4 = c(19L, 6L, 13L, 
18L, 8L, 17L, 19L, 6L, 13L), var5 = c(12L, 13L, 1L, 10L, 7L, 
3L, 12L, 13L, 1L), var6 = c(17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
17L, 17L), var7 = c(11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L
), var8 = c(16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L), var9 = c(18L, 
18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L), var10 = c(10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))

head(data,2)
#>   var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 var6 var7 var8 var9 var10
#> 1   12    5   18   19   12   17   11   16   18    10
#> 2    3    2   10    6   13   17   11   16   18    10

x = names(data[,-1])
out <- unlist(lapply(1, function(n) combn(x, 1, FUN=function(row) paste0("var1 ~ ", paste0(row, collapse = "+")))))
out
#> [1] "var1 ~ var2"  "var1 ~ var3"  "var1 ~ var4"  "var1 ~ var5" 
#> [5] "var1 ~ var6"  "var1 ~ var7"  "var1 ~ var8"  "var1 ~ var9" 
#> [9] "var1 ~ var10"

library(broom)
#> Warning: package 'broom' was built under R version 3.5.3

library(dplyr)
#> Warning: package 'dplyr' was built under R version 3.5.3
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

#To have the regression coefficients
tmp1 = bind_rows(lapply(out, function(frml) {
 a = tidy(lm(frml, data=data))
 a$frml = frml
 return(a)
}))
head(tmp1)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 6
#>   term        estimate std.error statistic p.value frml       
#>   <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>      
#> 1 (Intercept)    6.46      2.78      2.33  0.0529  var1 ~ var2
#> 2 var2           0.525     0.288     1.82  0.111   var1 ~ var2
#> 3 (Intercept)   -1.50      4.47     -0.335 0.748   var1 ~ var3
#> 4 var3           0.863     0.303     2.85  0.0247  var1 ~ var3
#> 5 (Intercept)    0.649     2.60      0.250 0.810   var1 ~ var4
#> 6 var4           0.766     0.183     4.18  0.00413 var1 ~ var4

#To have the regression results i.e. R2, AIC, BIC
tmp2 = bind_rows(lapply(out, function(frml) {
 a = glance(lm(frml, data=data))
 a$frml = frml
 return(a)
}))
head(tmp2)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 12
#>   r.squared adj.r.squared sigma statistic  p.value    df logLik   AIC   BIC
#>       <dbl>         <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl> <int>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     0.321         0.224  4.33      3.31  0.111       2  -24.8  55.7  56.3
#> 2     0.537         0.471  3.58      8.12  0.0247      2  -23.1  52.2  52.8
#> 3     0.714         0.673  2.81     17.5   0.00413     2  -20.9  47.9  48.5
#> 4     0.276         0.173  4.47      2.67  0.146       2  -25.1  56.2  56.8
#> 5     0             0      4.92     NA    NA           1  -26.6  57.2  57.6
#> 6     0             0      4.92     NA    NA           1  -26.6  57.2  57.6
#> # ... with 3 more variables: deviance <dbl>, df.residual <int>, frml <chr>

write.csv(tmp1, "Try_lm_coefficients.csv")
write.csv(tmp2, "Try_lm_results.csv")
```

<sup>Created on 2019-11-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much @Bappa Das! It works very well! I was having problem with installing broom (sorry, I am quite new)! thank you so much!

Comment: You may consider to accept the answer by clicking √.

Answer (score 1):

```
dat <- structure(list(var1 = c(12L, 3L, 13L, 17L, 9L, 15L, 12L, 3L, 
13L), var2 = c(5L, 2L, 15L, 11L, 13L, 6L, 5L, 2L, 15L), var3 = c(18L, 
10L, 14L, 16L, 8L, 20L, 18L, 10L, 14L), var4 = c(19L, 6L, 13L, 
18L, 8L, 17L, 19L, 6L, 13L), var5 = c(12L, 13L, 1L, 10L, 7L, 
3L, 12L, 13L, 1L), var6 = c(17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
17L, 17L), var7 = c(11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L
), var8 = c(16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L), var9 = c(18L, 
18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L), var10 = c(10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"))
```

We first write a function to obtain all the statistics you need. Note, rsq is the square of the correlation coefficient. So you don't need the linear model. The coefficient you get from the model is the slope.

```
STATS = function(x,y,DATA){
 COR = cor.test(DATA[,y],DATA[,x])
 MODEL = summary(lm(DATA[,y]~DATA[,x]))
 data.frame(
 VAR=x,
 PEARSON_COR=as.numeric(COR$estimate),
 PVAL=COR$p.value,
 RSQ=as.numeric(COR$estimate^2),
 SLOPE = MODEL$coefficients[2,1],
 stringsAsFactors=FALSE
 )
}
```

We test it on var2

```
STATS("var2","var1",dat)

     VAR PEARSON_COR      PVAL      RSQ     SLOPE
1 var2   0.5668721 0.1114741 0.321344 0.5251232
```

We do it for example on var2,var3,var4 and combine them into a data frame. Note I did not try var 6 to 10 because it's only 1 value

```
results = do.call(rbind,
lapply(c("var2","var3","var4"),function(i)STATS(i,"var1",dat)))
results

    VAR PEARSON_COR        PVAL       RSQ     SLOPE
1 var2   0.5668721 0.111474101 0.3213440 0.5251232
2 var3   0.7328421 0.024699805 0.5370575 0.8630573
3 var4   0.8450726 0.004127542 0.7141477 0.7660377
```

If you are familiar with tidyverse and purrr, you can do the following:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
c("var2","var3","var4") %>% map_dfr(STATS,"var1",dat)
```

Comment: Thank you! Your code looks and works well! When I try to apply it to my own data, it gives me the following error, just only when I apply the function
 
Error in cor.test.default(DATA[, y], DATA[, x]) : 
  'x' must be a numeric vector

Do you have any idea why? 
The dataset name it is correct and var2 results to be as numeric.

Also:
Is there a way to get the Coefficient of determination?
Thank you!

Comment: Hi @MarianoCGiglio, sorry, the coefficient of determination is RSQ in the above code. Ok just as a sanity check, if you do STATS("var2","var1",dat) it gives you this error? Did you include the quotations "" ?

Comment: I guess dat in your question is only a dummy dataset?

Comment: Yes, indeed, dat is a dummy dataset.
The code works well with "your" dataset, the one you posted in example, both the function and iterative works. But when I apply the code to my dataset I got that error, just applying the function (of course my dataset is called dat and var 2 is numeric). I included the quotations

Comment: ok if you do class(df$var1); class(df$var2), both gives numeric? If that's the case I 
 cannot tell. Either you dput() your dataset, or you share a link to it..

Answer (score 0):

There a several ways to do what you want in R. I suggest `sapply` which is a simple way to apply a function other a list of variables.
Here is an example to get the coefficients of each linear regression between var1 and all other variables.

```
# define a function to get coefficients from linear regression
do_lm <- function(var){ # var is the name of the column
  res <- lm(as.formula(paste0("var1~",var)), data = dat) # compute linear regression
  coefs <- c(intercept = res$coefficient[2], slope = res$coefficient[1]) # get coefficients
  return(coefs)
}

t(
  sapply(colnames(dat)[2:10], do_lm)
 )
# t transposes the result 
# sapply : applies on "var2" ... "var10" the function do_lm
```

It returns :

```
      intercept.var2 slope.(Intercept)
var2       0.5251232         6.4600985
var3       0.8630573        -1.4968153
var4       0.7660377         0.6490566
var5      -0.5047619        14.8158730
var6              NA        10.7777778
var7              NA        10.7777778
var8              NA        10.7777778
var9              NA        10.7777778
var10             NA        10.7777778
```

You can adapt the function `do_lm` in `sapply` to compute other things, like correlations ...

Comment: The OP is asking about `Correlation coefficient`, `p value` and `R_squared` generated from all the linear regressions.

Comment: Yes, it was just a minimal example of how to use the `sapply` function on linear regression in this case.

Comment: Thank you @gdevaux! Your code is nice and working well on my data! How can I get also other statistics, like p value and R_squared - Coefficient of determination?
Thank you!

Comment: You just need to add the other statistics in the `do_lm` function and return them

Comment: I am adding this, but it does not work

coefs <- c(intercept = res$coefficient[2], slope = res$coefficient[1], rsquared=$r.squared)

Comment: @Mariano C Giglio have you tried the solution provided by me? Just try it once it is having everything you want and it will be saved in .CSV file.