# performing all possible linear regressions between 1 variable and a list of variables

Tags: r

I am using the following code ( which was developed [in a previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58949703/r-repeat-linear-regression-for-all-variables-and-save-results-in-a-new-data-fra)) for the following task: performing all possible linear regressions between the first variable and the other variables and saving the results in a new data frame.

```
library(broom)
library(dplyr)
x <- names(data[,-1])
out <- unlist(lapply(1, function(n) combn(x, 1, FUN=function(row) 
          paste0("tlv ~ ", paste0(row, collapse = "+")))))
## get the regression coefficients
tmp1 = bind_rows(lapply(out, function(frml) {
      a = tidy(lm(frml, data=data))
      a$frml = frml
      return(a)
    }))
reg_coeff2 <- tmp1
 ## Get regression results i.e. R2, AIC, BIC
 tmp2 = bind_rows(lapply(out, function(frml) {
      a = glance(lm(frml, data=data))
      a$frml = frml
      return(a)
    }))
 reg_results2 <- tmp2
 reg_results2$frml <- sub("tlv ~ ", "", reg_results2$frml)
```

The code works very well, but I would like to implement it in order to do the following.

I have the following data frame (data)

```
structure(list(id = c(5309039, 5284969, 5300279, 5270289, 5259957, 
5267086, 5173196), var1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), var2 = c(23, 
24, 20, 32, 31, 37, 43), var3 = c(162, 154, 156, 154, 151.5, 
171, 154), var4 = c(62.8, 52.7, 64.5, 70.9, 63, 66.2, 60.3), 
    tlv = c(1049, 978, 1131, 1292, 1228, 1593, 1265), form20 = c(1674.12110392683, 
    1517.06018080512, 1666.03606715029, 1726.99450999549, 1627.94506984781, 
    1754.74878787639, 1608.54623766777), form19 = c(1062.84280028848, 
    902.364998653641, 1054.58187260355, 1116.8664734097, 1015.66220125765, 
    1145.22454880977, 995.841345244203), form18 = c(1050.91941325579, 
    891.3634649201, 1026.84722464179, 1073.58291322486, 980.997498562542, 
    1147.23019335865, 971.271632531001), form17 = c(1404.10436829839, 
    1220.98291088203, 1419.72032143583, 1517.11065788694, 1386.31581471687, 
    1477.21675910098, 1347.52393410332), form16 = c(1248.12292187059, 
    1126.73082253566, 1229.80850901466, 1265.36558733196, 1194.92548170827, 
    1321.39733067342, 1187.52592495257), form15 = c(990.132, 
    866.003, 1011.025, 1089.681, 992.59, 1031.918, 959.407), 
    form14 = c(1590.6052, 1436.4718, 1582.993, 1830.3706, 1688.692, 
    1812.3808, 1786.5202), form13 = c(1300.81321145176, 1130.23869905075, 
    1292.03253463863, 1358.23586808642, 1250.66417156907, 1388.37813595599, 
    1277.89625553694), form12 = c(1329.6, 1104.4, 1272, 1322.8, 
    1195.5, 1487.4, 1195.6)), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

and I need to perform linear regression between the variable `tlv` and all the variables whose name start with the prefix "form" , so excluding the other variables (i.e. `var1`, `var2`, `var3`, ...)

Comment: In your code, you are using `combn(x, 1)`  Not clear why you need that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the apply family to build needed formulas of all possible combinations then pass into `lm` iteratively. Except for `broom` functions, below demonstrates base R:

```
indvar_list <- lapply(1:9, function(x) combn(paste0("form", 12:20), x, simplify = FALSE)) 

formulas_list <- rapply(indvar_list, function(x) as.formula(paste("tlv ~", paste(x, collapse="+")))) 

tmp1 <- do.call(rbind, lapply(formulas_list, function(f)
   transform(tidy(lm(f, data=data)), frml = f)
))

tmp2 <- do.call(rbind, (lapply(formulas_list, function(f)
   transform(glance(lm(f, data=data)), frml = f)
))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can make it shorter with `map`

```
library(purrr)
tmp1 <- map_dfr(set_names(out, out),  ~ lm(.x, data = data) %>% tidy, .id = 'fmla')
tmp2 <- map_dfr(set_names(out, out),  ~ lm(.x, data = data) %>% glance, .id = 'fmla')
```

---

Or if we need only `form` variables, get the names of the columns that `startsWith` "form", pass it in `reformulate` to create a formula in `lm`, `tidy` the output and create the "Var" column signifying the column name (or if we need the formula itself, assign `reformulate` output to an object and call it later

```
startsWith(names(data), "form") %>%
    magrittr::extract(names(data), .) %>%
    map_dfr(~  lm(reformulate(.x, 'tlv'), data = data) %>% 
                  tidy %>%
                  mutate(Var = .x))
```

Similarly change `tidy` to `glance`

Answer (score 0):

We assume that the objective of getting the subsets is to find the best variables so instead of proceeding like that let us just find the "best" variables using using stepwise regression.

Since `data` has fewer rows than columns and `var1` is all 0's let us use the data frame `data2` shown below for our example.

First create the full model `fm0` and the use stepwise regression speciying the `var` variables as the lower bound, i.e. every model must contain them.

This runs quickly on this data and uses no packages.

```
data2 <- data[c("var2", "var3", "tlv", "form20", "form19")]

fm0 <- lm(tlv ~., data2)
varnames <- grep("var", names(data2), value = TRUE)
step(fm0, list(lower = reformulate(varnames)))
```

giving this model:

```
Call:
lm(formula = tlv ~ var2 + var3 + form20, data = data2)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)         var2         var3       form20  
  -2235.694       13.881        6.728        1.197
```